# How does calcium affect magnesium absorption?

Tags: physiology, calcium, magnesium, electrolytes

I was recently reading up on hypomagnesemia and found that hypoparathyroidism could be the cause of this imbalance. The book I was reading (Mosby's Manual of Diagnostic and Laboratory Tests) explained it as follows:

> In this disease, calcium levels are reduced. Calcium enhances intestinal absorption of
> magnesium, and with **low calcium** levels, **magnesium is not well absorbed**, so blood levels diminish. In hyperparathyroidism, calcium levels are high and magnesium levels increase.

I was curious to learn a little bit about the mechanism, so I googled, "How does calcium affect magnesium absorption?" Surprisingly, I got this as the response from Medscape:

> In the gut, calcium and magnesium intakes influence each other's absorption; a **high calcium** intake may **decrease magnesium absorption**...

I did not get much further in looking into the mechanism as I got stuck on this contradiction. How can this inconsistency be explained? Does calcium have a concentration dependent effect on magnesium absorption, or is there some other reasoning behind the differing explanations?

Medscape link: [https://www.medscape.com/answers/2038394-35946/how-is-magnesium-absorbed#:~:text=In%20the%20gut%2C%20calcium%20and,appears%20to%20increase%20magnesium%20absorption](https://www.medscape.com/answers/2038394-35946/how-is-magnesium-absorbed#:%7E:text=In%20the%20gut%2C%20calcium%20and,appears%20to%20increase%20magnesium%20absorption).

Comment: Can you include the Medscape link you quote?